# Connecting 2 water supply lines together to prevent stagnation?

Tags: plumbing

I am installing Pex in my house. I am using a home run system. I will have 1 outlet on the cold water manifold that  I will not be using. Instead of capping it off I would rather just use the last outlet. My plan is to connect (2) 1/2" water supply lines together using a "T". then Run the water line to an outdoor spigot. My theory is that water would flow through both 1/2" water lines equally anytime my outdoor spigot was used. I am just trying to prevent water stagnation and make sure all water lines are being used.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Why do  you think it would be a problem for water to sit in a pipe?

Comment: over time it would become stagnant in the dead end since its not moving or being replaced. At times when the water pressure would fluctuate or stop like during an extended hurricane outage the low or no pressure would allow that bad water to flow into the other used outlets.